# Por que module.exports no esta compartiendo variable entre multiple archivos?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo 3 archivos, constants.js, main.js y file1.js

En constant.js tengo una variable test que quiero poder editarlas en main.js y file.js.

La variable test la exporto con `module.exports = test`

Cuando obtengo la variable test en main.js y file.js y quiero editarla en ambos archivos, me doy cuenta que cada archivo tiene una copia de la variable, es decir la variable no es compartida por ambos archivos como quiero que suceda.

Ejemplo:

**constants.js**

```
var test = null

module.exports = { 
    test
}
```

**file1.js**

```
var { test } = require("./constant")

function foo() {
    test = 9
}

module.exports = { 
    foo
}
```

**main.js**

```
var { test } = require("./constant")
var file = require('./file1')


test = 5

console.log(test)
file.foo()
console.log(test)
```

**retorna**:

```
5
5
```

**que quiero que retorne:**

```
5
9
```

Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: No es que hagas nada mal, es el comportamiento natural de `require`. Para lo que necesitas hacer, deberías declarar `test` en el entorno `global`: `global.test = 5`. Por otro lado, lo que yo haría sería exponer una serie de funciones des de *constant.js* para aglutinar todo el tratamiento de la variable global.

Comment: No creo que necesite mucha más explicación. Si la necesitase, redactaré la respuesta formalmente.